# Getting the maximum value of records

Tags: sql

I am having a table called Withdrawals which has : Name, year, period, amount.

EX:

```
Name   Year    Period    Amount
--------------------------------
Jim    2010    1         100
Jim    2009    4         99
Jim    2009    3         17
Kim    2007    2         234
Ryu    2008    5         555
```

I was stuck that I can't get the latest value for the name & amount which has the recent year with the latest period.

I tried to use the query:

```
select max(year), max(period), name from withdrawarls
```

But I got wrong results.

So, how can I get the correct values:

```
Jim, 2010, 1, 100
Kim, 2007, 2, 234
RYU, 2008, 5, 555.
```

Answer (score 2):

In `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT name
        FROM    mytable
        ) td
JOIN    mytable t
ON      (t.year, t.period) =
        (
        SELECT  year, period
        FROM    mytable ti
        WHERE   ti.name = td.name
        ORDER BY
                name DESC, year DESC, period DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

In `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT name
        FROM    mytable
        ) td
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    mytable ti
        WHERE   ti.name = td.name
        ORDER BY
                year DESC, period DESC
        ) t
```

In `SQL Server` and `Oracle`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY year DESC, period DESC) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) t
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: I will try this and revert back. I hope that it will get the maximum year and the maximum period in the maximum year for each name. Thanks and will come back

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Withdrawals w
JOIN (Select Name, Max(year) year
      FROM Withdrawals
      group by name) t ON (t.Name = w.Name AND t.Year = w.Year)
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about the period? if there are values 3 and 4, it should choose the 4. how do I take the maximum period for that maximum year?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  from @tbl t
where t.year in (select max(year) from @tbl group by name)
```

With data you provided

```
declare @tbl table
(
    name varchar(10),
    year varchar(10),
    period int,
    amount int
)

insert into @tbl  select 'Jim', '2010', 1, 100
insert into @tbl select 'Jim', '2009', 4, 99
insert into @tbl select 'Jim', '2009', 3, 17
insert into @tbl select 'Kim', '2007', 2, 234
insert into @tbl select  'RYU', '2008', 5, 555

select *  from @tbl t
where t.year in (select max(year) from @tbl group by name)
```

Comment: Replace '*' with column names you need

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what about the period? If there are two period 3 , 4, it should should the maximum period also, so what should I include?

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(year), max(period), name from withdrawals group by name;
```

When using aggregate functions (ie min, max, count) the non-aggregated column should be listed in the "group by" clause. In this case "name".

Comment: No, this will not work, because in each year there are different periods and I should take the maximum period in the maximum year for each name

Answer (score 0):

Let's hope the Period is smaller than 100:

```
SELECT w.Name, w.Year, w.Period, w.Value
FROM Withdrawals w,
(SELECT Name, MAX(Year * 100 + Period) as maxTime
 FROM Withdrawals
 GROUP BY Name) AS maxW
WHERE w.Name = maxW.Name
AND w.Year * 100 + w.Period = maxW.maxTime
```

The problem with max(Year), max(Period) is that "2010 1" is later than "2009 4", while max(Year), max(Period) would return "2010 4", which does not exist. "Year * 100 + Period" gives you a good sorting.